AWS SCP Force tags to be used per created resource
I have a test AWS account in the company and I want every person who creates a resource, I have to put three tags type: project, user.
I have created them, now if they create a resource and put tag=project and in the value they put some wrong, it jumps an error.
The problem is that if they do not put anything, it allows to create the resource.
For it I have seen that it is necessary to create a SCP like the following one:
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "DenyEC2CreationSCP1",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:RunInstances",
        "ec2:CreateVolume"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "aws:RequestTag/Proyect": "true"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

This should fail if you create an EC2 instance resource or a volume without tags, the problem is that it still allows you to create it...
I wanted to know if the error could be that when I add the policy, I put it at root level, it does not let me put it at the lowest level which is DEV, even so, I understand that it should work to be root level:


SCP can't be applied to the management account, even if you set the target to Root. You have to use another account for the management account, and invite your production account in its organization. You'll then be able to use SCP on your production account.
